# How do I change this selector route so I can pass it as an argument to Selenium?

Tags: python, html, selenium, button, selector

I want to click on the button, but I don't know how to change the route. I want to do it with selector so I can put it in an infinite loop and iterate throught a full YouTube list.

```
boton = '#movie div.ytp-chrome-bottom > div.ytp-chrome-controls > div.ytp-left-controls > a.ytp-next-button.ytp-button'
buscador.find_element_by[enter image description here][1]_css_selector(boton).click()
```

[Image to clarify what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7P8yk.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to click each of those buttons then you can do the below

```
boton = '#movie div.ytp-chrome-bottom > div.ytp-chrome-controls > div.ytp-left-controls > a.ytp-next-button.ytp-button'
numberOfButtons = len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(boton))

# now iterate through all the buttons and click on them
for counter in range(numberOfButtons):
    driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(buton)[counter].click()
```

Comment: FYI, if the `buton` disappears after clicking then please change the `counter` to `0` in the last line so that it will pick-up the first item always after getting the elements.

Comment: I just copied the rute with Copy Selector in the html code. And thats the result, it is only one button, is the next button song play list in YouTube.